# Slow P2P sharing in ubuntu

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager, dns, bittorrent

Hi after installing ubuntu I found that my download speed , specifically torrent download speeds has gone surprisingly lower than before, I'm not really familiar with configuring network on Ubuntu/Linux so can anyone please help me with that?

And how can I check the problems/speeds of my DNS server I guess its a problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you got same problem as I did, your problem is having poorly supported network card, easiest way to fix that problem is to buy Linux supporting Ethernet card and re-install Linux.

There are some network cards which Linux doesn't support well or at all, so you must install the driver and remove old driver and add that unsupported driver to blacklist.

I can recommend TP-Link TG-3269 gigabit PCI Network adapter which is quite cheap (I paid 19€ which was overpriced), works great on my Ubuntu 14.04.

If you only got problem with P2P sharing being slow but normal internet downloads are fast etc. then it's as simple as just opening correct ports from your modem/router management page which is usually 192.168.1.1 depending what brand you use.